# Ibiza car hire late at night

Tags: car-rentals, spain, opening-hours

I booked tickets to Ibiza, arranged accommodation and am booking a car now but what I have found is that all offices close at 23:00. My flight is scheduled at 01:00 in night.

Is there a way to hire a car when we arrive?

Comment: Being Ibiza, there are probably more cars for hire at night than during the day!! :-)

Comment: Ok, I hired a bus transfer. When we arrived there were plenty of rental offices open. The information on their websites are utterly wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hertz claims to allow after hours pick up at Ibiza Airport. There's a 50 EUR fee which seems a bit excessive [probably you can get it waived if you have Gold Five Star status with them], plus you need to call to arrange directly.

https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/location/spain/ibiza/IBZT50

Click through to Qualifications and Requirements, and in the drop down box choose "Out of hours".

> **General requirements**
>
> - Flight number mandatory.
> - Premium Special (R6): Mercedes SLK Cabrio or similar is not available for out of hours.
>
> **Out of hours pick-up**
>
> For all Ryanair customers: Out of hours pick-up confirmed with Ryanair
>   flight number.
>
> For all other customers: Out of hours pick-up is available, but cannot
>   be booked via the Internet. Please contact your Reservation Centre as
>   specific information is required, namely:
>
> - your name and address.
> - your mobile phone number.
>
> An additional fee in the amount of EUR 49.36 (including tax) will
>   apply.

Alternatively a taxi to anywhere on the island is only about 30 EUR (as far as I remember) so it might be cheaper just to come back in the morning. There are taxis at the stand all night. Or even, taxi to your hotel with your family/friends and luggage and come back to the airport by yourself on the bus to pick up the car---it's a couple of euros for the bus fare.

Comment: Great response. I will take a shuttle from airport (we are 5) and then arrange a car rental next day. Ideally in Sant Josep and then returning to the airport. But it seems that I cannot book such combination online, all services know Ibiza airport only :-)

Comment: @LeosLiterak There is a seaport on Ibiza as well (Sant Antoni), might be car rentals there

Comment: Yes, there are. It seems funny that using taxi would be cheaper than renting a car.

Answer (score 3):

Leos!
I recommend you to use car rental comparison services like rental24h.com
By this link [Ibiza car rental](https://rental24h.com/spain/ibiza-airport) you will find all available cars and companies in Ibiza Airport. The results will filter all available companies for your time. Even if you arrive at 1 AM. I checked your request and find about 80 different cars available from Alamo, Europcar, Enterprise, OK and other companies. The price is started **from 13 EUR per day** for Fiat 500. Most of them have **free shuttle bus or Airport terminal pickup**.
I use this site to find all available car rental companies in my destination.
I hope this will help you in the future.

Comment: Are you sure that the car hire places that this broker offers are really open at that time, and don't change a late-collection fee? Have you personally used that broker for very late night collections without issue?

Comment: Yes. I rented cars many times with them. If you choose late hours they do not show you results from companies who do not operate in this time. Sometimes 9-6PM working companies have much better prices. But if you arrive at night you will see only cars and companies available for you.

Comment: Reads a bit spammy, if you ask me …

Comment: @Jan Sorry, if so. I just wish to help. The previous post just recommended to use Hertz and pay 50 EUR more for pick up.

Answer (score 2):

I work with [AirportCarHire.com](https://www.airportcarhire.com/spain/ibiza-airport.html)  and if you request a quote for an out of office time we will only display the car hire suppliers that are open for the  time you request. This applies to all  suppliers worldwide.